# Twisted compatible functools.lru_cache

Tags: python, twisted

I'm looking for something similar to [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) that works with functions that use twisted's `defer.inlineCallbacks` decorator. If I have the following:

```
import functools
import time
import treq

from twisted.internet import defer, reactor


@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=16)
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def something(arg):
    google_home_page = yield ping_google()
    response_text = yield google_home_page.text()
    defer.returnValue(arg in response_text)


def ping_google():
    return treq.get('https://www.google.com/')


def print_result(result):
    print('Time: {}, Result: {}'.format(time.time(), result))


def main():
    first = something('google')
    first.addCallback(print_result)

    random = something('other')
    random.addCallback(print_result)

    second = something('google')
    second.addCallback(print_result)

    third = something('google')
    third.addCallback(print_result)

    reactor.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As the example is now, the results are this (the order may change slightly but the result passed to the `print_results` callback are the same)

```
Time: 1577996575.9839969, Result: False
Time: 1577996575.984391, Result: True
Time: 1577996575.98441, Result: None
Time: 1577996575.98442, Result: None
```

I'm fairly confident this fails because the cache is holding onto the deferred returned by `something` rather than the deferred result. Does anyone know of a twisted friendly analog?

Thanks!